# "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! " in e2e test with JQM navigation

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I currently working on an Angular JS + JQM SPA. 
We use Angular JS for data binding and MVC and JQM for the UI components and navigation. 
e.g. $.mobile.changePage('#' + subPage);

It worked reasonably well ... until we started to set up e2e tests.

it seems that the $.mobile.changePage() is causing the dreadful "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error. I understand it is caused by an infinitive loop in the logic and i suspect it has something to do with the "location" ...

Do you guys have any ideas on how to work around this issue?

I am thinking of using the $location service to simulate JQM changePage ... but I am not sure how to archive this.

Thanks a lot in advance.